# Using prototypes in other files using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I'm currently learning how to use node.js (And OOP javascript with prototypes) but I've a little problem. I'll give you the code:

foo.js:

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.prototype.a = function(){
    return 'foo';
};
```

bar.js:

```
var bar = new Foo();
console.log(bar.a);
```

app.js

```
require('./foo.js');
require('./bar.js');
```

Instead of working I get a ReferenceError telling me that foo is not defined. Can somebody tell me how I should do this?

Comment: You need to understand how Node modules work.  In particular, globals aren't really global. http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 2):

First, proper export:

**foo.js**

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.prototype.a = function(){
    return 'foo';
};

exports.ref_to_foo = foo;
```

and then proper import:

**bar.js**

```
var foo_module = require('./foo.js');
var Foo = foo_module.ref_to_foo;

var bar = new Foo();
console.log(bar.a);
```

Comment: Is export a module or is it default in node.js?

Comment: @RobinVandenBroeck `exports` is a special object in each module which is visible outside of the module (and no other object is visible outside).